# NameError when trying to import function from another script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nameerror

I've seen many posts on this and the solution always seems to be to add `*` when importing the original script to be able to access its functions. I have done this and still get the error.

I have a file called `toolbox.py` whose path is:  `/Users/justinbenfit/Desktop/Programming/Python/Explorium /transformations_deduping/ipynb/toolbox.py` and contains the following:

```
def tz():
    print('works')
```

Then I have a file called `explorium_check_acceptable.ipynb` whose path is:  `/Users/justinbenfit/Desktop/Programming/Python/Explorium /transformations_deduping/ipynb/explorium_check_acceptable.ipynb`

and contains:

```
from toolbox import *
tz()
```

which results in:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/cf/ft88j_856fv5rk3whgs12d9w0000gq/T/ipykernel_20696/4114475549.py in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 from toolbox import *
----> 4 tz()

NameError: name 'tz' is not defined
```

I don't know what else could be wrong unless you can't import functions from a .py file to a .ipynb file.

update:
I ran

```
!export PYTHONPATH=.
!python -m site
```

in one of my ipynb code blocks and got this:

```
sys.path = [
    '/Users/justinbenfit/Desktop/Programming/Python/Explorium /transformations_deduping/ipynb',
    '/Users/justinbenfit/opt/anaconda3/lib/python39.zip',
    '/Users/justinbenfit/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9',
    '/Users/justinbenfit/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/justinbenfit/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
    '/Users/justinbenfit/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aeosa',
    '/Users/justinbenfit/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/locket-0.2.1-py3.9.egg',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/justinbenfit/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/justinbenfit/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

Comment: You're not importing what you think you're importing.  What does `help(toolbox)` and `dir(toolbox)` show? You're importing another module named `toolbox` .

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? (aka restart the ipython kernel or something like that)

Comment: Thanks for the response! help(toolbox) results in another nameerror: ```NameError: name 'toolbox' is not defined```

Comment: dir(toolbox) also throws the name error and I tried restarting the kernal to no avail

Comment: for `help(toolbox)` you need to do `import toolbox` first (not `from toolbox import *`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug `import` issues, it is always helpful to view (and post on SO) the output of `python -m site`, which will reveal the contents of `sys.path` in a readable way.

You will usually want

```
export PYTHONPATH=.
```

or similar, to ensure that current directory is in sys.path.

Notice that you'll need that export
in the context of the running python kernel,
when you start it.
Also, the current working directory
at time of starting will make a difference.
Inspect sys.path within your notebook to verify,
perhaps using:

```
from pprint import pp
import sys

pp(sys.path)
```

---

It appears you have this module in your path:
https://pypi.org/project/toolbox

Try

```
from toolbox import Item
```

to verify that.

Also, as a very generic way of testing such import details,
a rename to e.g. `toolbox1.py` is a good sanity check.
That is, we expect the import's success to track
whether it has caught up with the new name yet, or not.

A classic example is some poor student naming a file `test.py`.
Notice that `python -c 'import test'` always succeeds,
since there is a seldom-used builtin `test` module.

---

Prefer

```
from toolbox import tz
```

over the `*` format.
It makes your code easier to read and to analyze.
And here, it would offer a clearer diagnostic,
failing in the import statement rather than waiting until the tz() reference.

Comment: I have added the `python -m site` output above. I'm not sure I did it right or what to look for to be honest. I tried to import Item from toolbox and got an import error. I'm not sure what's causing it. I changed the name of the module and and the import in the .ipynb said not accessed until I changed the name there to the new module so it appears to be referencing the correct script. And upon testing it again it did import and run the function. Thanks!